# Background-Only Opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some trouble with CSS.

I have code (example):

```
<div class="background" style="background: url(sample.jpg) no-repeat;">
    <div class="text-title">Title</div>
    <div class="text">Random stuff</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, that when hovering on this background image - it should get opacity to lets say 0.3, but how to make it, that inside items would stay the same opacity 1?

Comment: By "inside items" you mean `Title` and `Random stuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the best trick in the book. https://jsfiddle.net/xbxvr8as/

If you have trouble with CSS then this might well bend your brain but the jsfiddle is as pared down as you can get it. Play with it by removing single styles to see what happens.

The crux is to `relative:position` your element. Then you can add a "pretend" extra div-like thing using the `:after` pseudo-element. You give this pseudo-element a bunch of properties - the most important probably being `position:absolute` which allows it to sit straight underneath the text.

HTML

```
<div id="a">
    some stuff in here .....
</div>
```

CSS

```
#a{position:relative}
#a:after{
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    background-color:#f00;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Comment: I have a several items every of them takes 20% of width, this absolute thing, puts them in one spot. No other way without absolute positioning?

Comment: No it doesn't - look - https://jsfiddle.net/xbxvr8as/1/ . Basically you are only positioning elements on your page `position:relative`. The absolute position is happening on elements that, technically, don't actually exist on your page - they are just being put there on the fly by CSS.

Comment: ...if you `position:absolute` an element it will be positioned absolutely relative to the entire page. However, if you nest the absolute element in another element which has `position:relative` it will be positioned relative to that instead. This is a very useful trick - parent = relative position, child = absolute position. Understanding this principle is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pseudo element.

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="text-title">Title</div>
    <div class="text">Random stuff</div>
</div>
```

```css
.background {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow; /* added for illustrative purposes */
    min-height: 150px; /* added for illustrative purposes */
}
.background:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-3.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kbf5p5x/

Comment: I have a several items every of them takes 20% of width, this absolute thing, puts them in one spot. No other way without absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the background on an absolutely-positioned element within the outer element, and then control its opacity independently:

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div class="background" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: url(sample.jpg) no-repeat;">
    </div>
    <div class="text-title">Title</div>
    <div class="text">Random stuff</div>
</div>
```

Note that to do that, we have to make its container positioned via `position: relative`.

**Live Example:**

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.background {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" style="position: relative">
  <div class="background" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: url(http://onlyfreewallpaper.com/download/sea-coast-night-sky-stars-milky-way-1024x768.jpg) no-repeat;">
  </div>
  <div class="text-title">Title</div>
  <div class="text">Random stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a several items every of them takes 20% of width, this absolute thing, puts them in one spot. No other way without absolute positioning?

Comment: @JustinasTalandis: Just change the `left` and/or `top` of them as appropriate.